# Project Settings Recommends Compiler Warning: "Suspicious Moves"

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-warnings

In an Xcode project, I'm getting a weird warning. What is it and is it a bad thing?

Here's the warning:

> Project 'Little Hoot' - Enable Recommended Warning
>   This will enable the following recommended compiler warning:

- Suspicious Moves

It is also recommending I updated another setting too.

> Target 'Little Hoot' - Update C++ Standard Library
>   The 'libstdc++' C++ Standard Library is deprecated. This will update the setting for Target 'Little Hoot' to 'Compiler Default', which is the recommended value.

I have looked online and I'm unable to find an answer for at least the first warning.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got this message from Xcode recently while setting up a new project.  My steps were removing the reference from files (such as Info.plist), creating folders directly on Finder, and adding files back to Xcode. I suppose it's a security feature but if your case is like mine, it's only a warning.

Answer (score 4):

The "Suspicious Moves" Project/Target setting seems to control the `-Wmove` compiler warning optionin LLVM/Clang, which is a group of 3 other warning options: `-Wpessimizing-move`, `-Wredundant-move` and `-Wself-move`.

Those options generate these warnings:

```
warning: moving a temporary object prevents copy elision
warning: moving a local object in a return statement prevents copy elision
warning: redundant move in return statement
warning: explicitly moving variable of type A to itself
```

(From the Clang documentation at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html)

So it's probably not a big deal whether you accept the recommendation and enable the warning, or go without it. You just won't be told if you make things slower with those suspicious moves.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these warnings refer to settings in your project not reflecting the recommended defaults. They were probably both triggered after you upgraded your version of Xcode or imported an old project into a later version of Xcode.

Unless you have good reasons to do otherwise, it is best to follow the recommendation. The easiest way to do that is click in the yellow triangles that accompany the warnings and allow Xcode to make the appropriate changes to the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn all warnings on, with the exceptions of pedantic warnings, unused parameters, and auto-synthesised properties; these three warnings warn for tons of good code. Same for static analyser warnings.

Then you look at what warnings you get and fix them. If you haven't done this before, then I'll estimate that 20-40% of all warnings are actual bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll be able to `see warning detail in issue navigator section`. You can fix it by selecting issue. This will show an alert stating necessary changes to be done in project settings.

**Click on Perform Changes button**. This will make necessary changes in Project settings and thereby removing this warning.